# Adding n bits to the first n bits of another number

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, addition

I am doing a project on digital filters. I needed to know how to add a 4 bit binary number to the most significant 4 bits of an 8 bit number. For example:

```
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 //x 
+ 1 0 1 0         //y
= 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 //z
```

Can I add using a code somewhat like this?

```
z=[7:4]x + y
```

or should I have to concatenate the 4 bit number with another four zeros and add?

Comment: I'm sorry. I got confused. It didn't add the 4 bits to msb, it performed normal addition.

Comment: so you basically retract the question?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what you said.

Comment: Does this mean that you don't want any more answers to your original question?

Comment: Actually I'm new at this. A friend advised me to ask for help here. I'm learning how to use the android app.

Comment: I ask you: do you want more answers to the question you posted?

Comment: Yes, It would be useful to know other methods too.

Comment: I think @mcleod_ideafix answer is the **right** one, so you might want to add a comment to that answer why you don't think it answers your question completely. If you think it answers your question, please upvote and accept that answer.

Comment: Upvote requires some level 15, which i don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `y` is the 4 bit number and `x` the 8 bit number:

If you do

```
assign z = x[7:4] + y
```

Then you are doing a 4-bit addition and the most significant part of `z` is padded with 0's.

If you do

```
assign z = y[7:4] + x
```

You will get an error message from the synthesizer, as subscripts for `y` are wrong.

So do as this:

```
assign z = {y,4'b0} + x
```

Which performs an 8-bit addition with `x` and the value of `y` shifted 4 bits to the left, which is want you wanted.

Comment: That was very helpful. Now i know where i was wrong.